# Joda - "hh:mm AM" is malformed at "AM"

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm using Joda library for formatting strings like `hh:mm am/pm` to `LocalTime` in my android app, So I'm using this:

```
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a").parseLocalTime("6:30 AM");
```

It works fine, But when I change my phone language (to germany or spanish) it throwns this exception:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "06:30 AM" is malformed at "AM"
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this using locale English:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH).parseLocalTime("6:30 AM");
```

Comment: Note i think u may use Spanish in .withLocale(Locale.SPANISH); it may give result and also ("hh:mm aa")

Comment: Thanks, bu `withLocale()` should be before `parseLocalTime()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm aa").parseLocalTime("6:30 AM");
```